# Create personal POI for google maps

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on a project where my customer has to administrate (delete & add) several addresses (locations) on a google map.

This map needs to be inserted in a website with all the POIs.
Also the app needs to be embedded in android app and ios app.

The point now is how can I make it possible for the customer to administrate all locations?

When using the:

- Google Maps Android API
- Google Maps for iOS
- Google Maps JavaScript API

Might be super easy but I miss this puzzle....

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Some code examples. Why are they not working? etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Dear Tom, well it is not about the development. I just want to know if there is a way to centrally manage POI's via the goolge interface to share it on repectively on every device where the map is embedded. For administrate a map and share it on a website its easy but i dont know how to share such google map on android or ios? may sound odd.... ,-/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/) - service that enables users to create custom maps for personal use or sharing ([mymaps](/questions/tagged/mymaps) on stackoverflow). But take into account that currently there is no any API to access My Maps programmatically.